# Generic validation method c#

Tags: c#

I have this current method that looks like this:

```
public static class ThrowIf
{
    public static void ArgumentIsNull(params Expression<Func<object>>[] exprs)
    {
        foreach (var expr in exprs)
        {
            var member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
            var name = member?.Member.Name ?? "Unknown";
            var value = expr.Compile()();

            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is great. I can invoke it like this:

```
ThrowIf.ArgumentIsNull(() => model, () => model.Lines);
```

Instead of doing this:

```
If (model == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
If (model.Lines == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model.Lines));
```

Inspired by this extension method, I decided to create a validation method. I did it like this:

```
public static class ValidateIf
{
    public static string IsNullOrEmpty(params Expression<Func<object>>[] exprs)
    {
        foreach (var expr in exprs)
        {
            var member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
            var name = member?.Member.Name ?? "Unknown";
            var value = expr.Compile()();

            if (value == null) return $"{name} cannot be null.";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And I without thinking I used it like this:

```
ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(
    () => line.ProductCode,
    () => line.Currency,
    () => line.Dates);
```

The problem with this is that the return type is not used.
I would have to do something like this:

```
return ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(
    () => line.ProductCode,
    () => line.Currency,
    () => line.Dates);
```

But in my code, is is used a bit like this:

```
public string ValidateSynchronize(OrderViewModel model)
{
    ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(
        () => model.Account,
        () => model.Account.OpeningTimes,
        () => model.Account.VehicleRouting,
        () => model.Lines
    );
    foreach (var line in model.Lines)
        ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(
            () => line.Delivery,
            () => line.Delivery.OpeningTimes,
            () => line.Delivery.VehicleRouting,
            () => line.Product
        );

    return null;
}
```

Which would have to become this:

```
public string ValidateSynchronize(OrderViewModel model)
{
    var message = ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(
        () => model.Account,
        () => model.Account.OpeningTimes,
        () => model.Account.VehicleRouting,
        () => model.Lines
    );
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) return message;

    foreach (var line in model.Lines)
    {
        message = ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(
            () => line.Delivery,
            () => line.Delivery.OpeningTimes,
            () => line.Delivery.VehicleRouting,
            () => line.Product
        );
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) return message;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Which is a bit ugly, and when I have methods like this:

```
public async Task<string> ValidateSaveAsync(OrderViewModel model, IStockProvider stockProvider)
{
    ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(
        () => model.Account,
        () => model.Account.Currency,
        () => model.AccountNumber,
        () => model.ReferenceNumber,
        () => model.Source,
        () => model.OrderDate,
        () => model.Type,
        () => model.Lines);

    var validationMessage = Validate(model);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
        return validationMessage;

    foreach (var line in model.Lines)
    {
        ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(
            () => line.Product,
            () => line.Product.ProductCode,
            () => line.UnitOfMeasure,
            () => line.Currency,
            () => line.Currency.UnitPrice,
            () => line.Currency.LineValue,
            () => line.Currency.IssueReference,
            () => line.Currency.IssueNumber,
            () => line.Dates);

        if (!ValidationExtensions.IsIssueNumberValid(line.Currency.IssueNumber)) return "Price Issue Number is invalid, must be greater than 0";
        if (!ValidationExtensions.IsRequiredDateValid(line.Dates.Required)) line.Dates.Required = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date;
        if (!ValidationExtensions.IsDespatchDateValid(line.Dates.Dispatch)) line.Dates.Dispatch = DateTime.Now.Date;
        if (!ValidationExtensions.IsDeliveryDateValid(line.Dates.Delivery)) line.Dates.Delivery = DateTime.Now.Date;
        if (!ValidationExtensions.IsUnitPriceValid(line.Currency.UnitPrice)) return "Unit price is invalid, must be between 0 and 30";
        if (!ValidationExtensions.ValidateQuantity(line.Type, line.Quantity)) return $"Minimum of 1.5M and maximum of 22M order quantity on cut - lengths - Line:{line.Id}";
        if (!ValidationExtensions.IsRollAvailable(line.Type, line.UnitOfMeasure, line.Product.Roll30Available)) return $"30M rolls not allowed - Line:{line.Id}";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Type) || model.Type.Equals("S", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) continue;
        if (ValidationExtensions.IsProductDiscontinued(line.Product.Status))
            return $"Product discontinued - Line:{line.Id}";

        // TODO: Matt asked me to add this, see the comment below
        // I believe it is when they choose a particular lot number when ordering a roll as the qty for rolls is always 1 yet the stock can be
        // any size... for now if the ordered item type is a roll ignore this validation check.
        if (line.Type == OrderLineType.Roll || string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.LotNumber)) continue;

        var stock = await stockProvider.GetAsync(line.LotNumber);

        if (line.Quantity >= stock.Quantity) continue;

        return $"Selected lot {line.LotNumber} has changed - quantities no longer match (requested {line.Quantity} got {stock.Quantity}) Line {line.Id}";
    }

    return null;
}
```

It is a mess...
So, is there a neat trick I could use or another way to return a string only if it has a value?
I know it is unlikely, but I thought I would ask before implementing the ugly solution :(

Comment: "another way to return a string only if it has a value" - you already know a way to do it - if this is an *exceptional* circumstance...

Comment: It may be tidier if you followed the 'try' pattern like `int.TryParse`, i.e. `if (ValidateIf.IsNullOrEmpty(x, out message)) { handle error }`. Other than exceptions not sure what else you can do.

Comment: Just so you know, that expression approach will massively slow down your code. Compiling something into a runtimeassembly just to check for nulls is a bit excessive.

Comment: if you are using ASP why not use model validation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: I just was figthing reading all the code. What I totally dont understand is, why you need expressions at all? Can't you just have a void ArgumentIsNull(params object[] o) and return o.Any(x => x == null). Caller could just call like: ArgumentsisNull(model, model?.Lines)

Comment: Can you write that as an answer for me please?